# Get uniques elements

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 4 };
```

Using `var intersect = array1.Intersect(array2);`I got

```
2
3
```

but I need to get

```
  1
  4
```

Can you give me any advice how I can do it using Linq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array1.Union(array2).Except(array1.Intersect(array2))
```

Explanation:

1. First you calculate set union of two sequences: `1, 2, 3, 4`
2. You are calculating intersection of sets: `2, 3`
3. You are finding set difference between all items and intersection: `1, 4`

Comment: Is there a reason for using Contact instead of Union?

Comment: @m1o2 nope, actually you are right, Union would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 4 };

    var result = array1.Concat(array2).Except(array1.Intersect(array2));
    foreach (var item in result)
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
```

Output :

> 1
>
> 4

Comment: How does this answer contribute more than what [Sergey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24446878/238902) has already provided? They discussed `Concat` in that answer and realized `Union` is better. Why post an answer with that solution again?

Comment: But sergey use Union and i suggest to use concat also i don't saw him use concat and i think it gives the same result.